# Not able to execute the application in Struts 2

Tags: java, configuration, struts2, action-mapping

I am new to struts 2 and wrote a helloworld application in it. But when I run the index.jsp file on Tomcat server it displays

Configuration file code is

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
              web.xml
<display-name>mayank</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <filter>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <filter-class>
         org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.ng.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
      </filter-class>
   </filter>
   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
 </web-app>
```

struts.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
   <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
      <package name="helloworld" extends="struts-default">
            <action name="hello" class="com.action.HelloWorldAction" method="execute">
            <result name="success">/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
      </action>
   </package>
</struts>
```

UPDATE: finally resolved many exceptions but now getting an exception at struts.xml

STACK TRACE: 
This is the Stack trace of the error on the console. I think there is some problem with my struts.xml but i am not able to figure it out.

```
Jan 08, 2016 1:17:50 PM org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher warn    WARNING: Could not find action or result: /mayank/hello.action?name=da
    There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [hello] associated with context path [/mayank]. - [unknown location]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:185)
        at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:63)
        at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:37)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:58)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:554)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:81)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: post your struts.xml

Comment: post the url where you use index.jsp

Comment: Hi , actually i figured out that my console is throwing an exception  Unable to load [unknown location] caused by: Unable to load file WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml @Abdelhak

Comment: Try to post all your stacktrace

Comment: @Abdelhak I have posted the stack trace. Actually i resolved the first exceptions by putting struts.xml in /WEB-INF from /WEB-INF/classes. I dont know but it worked :P

Comment: because it is the default place

Comment: @Abdelhak But this exception is annoying me. I guess compiler is not able to get HELLOWORLDACTION class or something like that

Comment: what kind of exception

Comment: @Abdelhak I have edited the post you can see the stack trace over there. It is regarding the mapping.

Comment: What ? struts.xml must be in the root of the classpath. WEB-INF\classes, not just WEB-INF. The JSPs should stay in another subfolder under WEB-INF.